# Is there a possibilitie to get an older version of an overwritten .r file?

Tags: r, recovery

Somehow an .r file got overwritten and is absolutly empty now. Is there a possibilitie to get a older version of the file? The onboard solution of Win 10 is not working.

Comment: Can you check the .Rhistory file? (or the history tab next to 'environment') hopefully the code ran through your console

Comment: I did this and some parts of the code are there but other parts unfortunately not.  Are there further ways to get old parts of the code?

Comment: Rstudio did introduce an autosave (https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/03/rstudio-1-3-preview-the-little-things/). You can check if it was enabled....

Comment: it was enabled and I was able to save most of my code, the problem is, that RStudio always delets the content of the .r file while saving OR opening it. Does anybody know why this is happening. The last package that I installed before was the **janitor** package